# How do I make a modal in bootstrap?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I just have copy and paste the modal example in bootstrap website and its not working, How can I do for it work? Like when i click in the button it didnt open.
        Launch demo modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
 <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-  labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>One fine body…</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What isn't working, what code do you have so far?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that I have written.. Now its there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all informations here [Bootstrap modal](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) [Bootstrap Examples](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html#examples)
`$('#myModal').modal('show')` will show your modal

you can add a button with id=Btn and do this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#Btn').live("click", function() {

$("#modal").modal("show");

});

});
```